# MySQL Query - How to count foreign key occurence from second table with three table connected?

Tags: mysql

Here's my data sample:

```
product
--------------------------------
| product_id PK | product_name |
--------------------------------
| FRT1          | Apple        |
| FRT2          | Orange       |
| TXT1          | Ribbon       |
--------------------------------

package
-------------------------
| package_id PK | price |
-------------------------
| P001          | 1000  |
| P002          | 1500  |
| P003          | 1000  |
-------------------------

package_detail
---------------------------------
| package_id FK | product_id FK |
---------------------------------
| P001          | FRT1          |
| P002          | FRT1          |
| P002          | FRT2          |
| P003          | FRT2          |
---------------------------------
```

The key for searching is product_name, so if I search "Apple", result should be like this:

```
-------------------------------------------
| package_id | price | num_of_package_dtl |
-------------------------------------------
| P001       | 1000  | 1                  |
| P002       | 1500  | 2                  |
-------------------------------------------
```

I'm weak at joining, can anyone help me with the query?
Thank you in advance~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  b.package_id, c.price, d.totalCount
FROM    product a
        INNER JOIN package_detail b 
            ON a.product_ID = b.product_ID
        INNER JOIN package c
            ON b.package_ID = c.package_ID
        INNER JOIN 
        (
          SELECT package_id, COUNT(*) totalCount
          FROM package_detail
          GROUP BY  package_id
        ) d ON d.package_ID = b.package_ID
WHERE a.product_name = 'apple'
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/90b0c/10)

Comment: It worked, thank you very much. Inner join thrice @@, my brain can't handle it. I'm going to break and study this query. Again, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

Select pd.package_id, p.price, count(*) as num_of_package_dtl from package_detail pd join package p on p.package_id = pd.package_id join Product pt on pt.product_id = pd.product_id where pd.product_name = 'Apple' group by pd.package_id, p.price

Comment: "package_detail pd" doesn't have "product_name" field. I tried changing "pd.product_name" to "pt.product_name". Result isn't what I wanted, it show all package that has "Apple" and all count is "1"

Comment: What result are you expecting? A count of one for each price seems correct to me given your result set.

Comment: My result may contain count of 2 or more, and the count is for product in each package, not the price. As you see in my sample, the first row count result is 1, and the second row is 2, not 1. I got the expected result using John Woo's answer. Thank you for answering. @Darren Naylor